# Getting the "name" of the smartcard for SCardGetCardTypeProviderName()

Tags: smartcard, winscard

In order to get a crypto context from `CryptAcquireContext()`, I need to know the provider name for the smartcard currently in the slot.

According to the documentation, `SCardGetCardTypeProviderName()` will do this, but param 2 is the card name, and I can't see how to determine this non-interactively. All the documentation/examples I've seen either harcode a name or rely on `SCardUIDlgSelectCard()`, which displays a UI.

Similarly reading around `SCardLocateCards()`, although it takes a list of smartcard names (for which I'm populating from `SCardListCards()`, it doesn't seem to pass back anything that identifies the name of the smartcard inserted.

I suspect I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing something. `SCardLocateCards` returns as part of the strucutre the ATR of the smartcard, which can then be used in `SCardListCards`:

```
SCARD_READERSTATE smartcardState[MAXIMUM_SMARTCARD_READERS];

result = SCardLocateCards (context, cardsList, smartcardState, readerCount);
if (result == SCARD_S_SUCCESS) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < readerCount; i++)
    {
        if (SCARD_STATE_ATRMATCH & smartcardState[i].dwEventState) {
            break;
        }
    }

    result = SCardListCards (NULL, smartcardState[i].rgbAtr, NULL, NULL, cardName, &count);
    if (result == SCARD_S_SUCCESS) {
        // Cardname for CryptAquireContext in cardName
    }
}
```

If anyone has a better route forward let me know - I think this is the only way though from what I can see.